# Participant Import: Mandatory key(s) missing from params array: line_total

Tags: civievent, import, participants

I am currently trying to import a number of participants that registered through an external service.  I first imported all the contacts - then proceeded to import particpants

The current fields I am trying to import are

- Email:Email Match to Contact
- Number of Tickets:Fee Level (I guess matching to my price set)
- 1:Participant Status ID (Registered)
- Registration Date: Date Registered

The import will begin - the first participant will import, then it will fail and say: `Mandatory key(s) missing from params array: line_total`

I thought maybe it was a bad contact - but no - it will always import the first participant and fail - regardless of the order I have the CSV in.

Any thoughts?

When I change the Fee Levels from `1` to `Tickets - 1: 1`, the import goes through - but the price set is not actually selected after the import is completed.